# Subtracting Arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have sliced two arrays into their corresponding x and y values. I want to subtract the x-values and the y-values.

```
arrayOneXValue = clusterCenters[:,0]
arrayTwoXValue = createArray[:,0]
arrayOneYValue = clusterCenters[:,1]
arrayYValue = createArray[:,1]

subtractXValues = np.subtract(arrayOneXValue, arrayTwoXValue)
subtractYValues = np.subtract(arrayOneYValue, arrayTwoXValue)

print(subtractXValues)
print(subtractYValues)
```

I was expecting to see two arrays with the subtracted values corresponding to the x and y values in them. Instead I receive:

```
ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types 
    dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

Any suggestions on why I am receiving this message and where my logical error is, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the arrays' `dtypes`?

Comment: I did not declare it specifically but calling the numpy.ndarray.dtype function gives: <class 'numpy.dtype'>

Comment: Tell us about the arrays that you are trying to subtract.  For example `arrayOneXValue.shape` and `arrayOneXValue.dtype`, etc.  Or complete the line ` types dtype('`

Comment: OK, I did an edit, and found that your formatting cut off the error message. Now it is clear that your arrays contain strings, not numbers.  So the problem is before this in how you construct, or download those arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A possible error I noticed is in the line:

```
subtractYValues = np.subtract(arrayOneYValue, arrayTwoXValue)
```

The second matrix is **arrayTwoXValue** instead of **arrayYValue**. Perhaps it should be:

```
subtractYValues = np.subtract(arrayOneYValue, arrayYValue)
```

Additionally, the error is caused by a mismatch in array datatypes. If you posted an example of what the arrays contained, I could elaborate. However, here is an example.

```
a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([1, 'a'])
c = np.subtract(a, b)
```

> **Ouput:** TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('U21') dtype('U21') dtype('U21')